# No response from Services Entity API when added '.json' to the end of alias

Tags: 7, entities, services

While configuring [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module, when I add '.json' to the end of the resource alias I get an emtpy page. Other resources that are not provided via [Services Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_entity) output json the same way. The [Services Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_entity) module have no documentation in this direction. Any ideas?

Edit: Also adding '.xml' gives empty response which points to that I am doing something wrong:)

Comment: What's in your logs? Are you sure your webserver is not configured to return json and xml as is, without even trying to run your index.php? Is index.php even called for such requests? I'm guessing now, but well, that was the reason for me in similar circumstances.

Comment: @Molot thank you for the comment. I found out that I put the suffix at the end of the alias like I did with other resources. But in this case I had to put it at the end of the whole url. Ie: http://example.com/endpoint/resource_alias/resource_id.json or http://example.com/api/entity_node/5.json

Comment: It worked? Great. Put self answer and I'll gladly upvote it :)

Comment: Yep, sure :) Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey,

You shouldn't add the suffixes like .json or .xml to the end of the alias name like you do with some other resources if the resources are provided by services_entity module. Adding the suffix directly to end of the whole url solved it.

`example.com/endpoint/resource_alias/resource_id.json` ie:
`example.com/api/entity_node/5.json`